# How to get the progress of a long pymysql executemany operation?

Tags: python, mysql

I am using Python to load some big CSVs(about 2G each) into a MySQL database.I tried `cursor.executemany()` to achieve this, however I find it hard to monitor the progress of this operation. Is there any way to add a progress bar like `tqdm` on this method? Or is there other way to do this? Thanks!